# Asp.Net Identity find users not in role

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I need to find all users that DONT'T contain a certain role, using Asp.Net Identity.
So far I have something like this but it is not working.

```
(From role In context.Roles
From userRoles In role.Users
Join us In context.Users On us.Id Equals userRoles.UserId
Where role.Name <> "SomeRole"
Select us.UserName)
```

This give me a list of all users but it includes users in role "SomeRole".
It looks I need some type of not in sub query?

Here is the SQL code that works but I would still like the LINQ query if possible.

```
select distinct A.UserName from AspNetUsers A
inner join AspNetUserRoles UR on UR.UserId = A.Id
inner join AspNetRoles R on R.Id = UR.RoleId
where not exists(
    select AspNetUserRoles UR1 on UR1.UserId = A.Id
    inner join AspNetRoles R1 on R1.Id = UR1.RoleId 
    where R1.Name = 'SomeRole')
```

Well I have a working solution but it is not pretty and I'm sure it can be written better.

```
(From role In context.Roles
From userRole In role.Users
Join user In context.Users On us.Id Equals userRole.UserId
Where Not (
    From role1 In context.Roles
    From userRole1 In role1.Users
    Join user1 In context.Users On user1.Id Equals userRoles1.UserId
    Where role1.Name = "SomeRole"
    Select user1.Id).Contains(user.Id)
Select user.UserName).Distinct()
```

Comment: Sorry the above code was in VB but in C# it is !=  I did not tag the article as VB or C#.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In c# you can get all users that are not in a certain role like this:

```
var role = context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "role");
var usersNotInRole = context.Users.Where(m => m.Roles.All(r => r.RoleId != role.Id));
```

Comment: This does not work because Asp.Net Identity does not have a "Role" class directly. To get to the "Role" class it is off the contextRoles.Users. Which is where I am stuck.

Comment: @goroth you can lazy load Roles from Users but default name is "IdentityRole". updated answer.

Comment: there is no "IdentityRole" off the Users. This is where it gets confusing because I do have a ApplicationRole class that inherited IdentityRole but LINQ will not query the ApplicationRole class directly.

Answer (score 3):

User Entity Framework's Join

```
ApplicationRole superAdminRole = await _context.Roles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == "SuperAdmin");

IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> users =await _context.UserRoles.Join(_context.Users, x => x.UserId, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new
{
    User = y,
    RoleId = x.RoleId
}).Where(x => x.RoleId != superAdminRole.Id)
  .Select(x => x.User)
  .ToListAsync();
```